# How to insert header in generated files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't find how to have generated files contain a header (with copyright info, etc.) in Rails 2.3.

I'd like all files generated automatically by the Rails Generator to have this header at the beginning of the file. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a rake test to add the headers to all the files. Check out how it works on the Annotate gem (http://github.com/ctran/annotate_models). You'll likely have to run it on all your .rb files, but the main idea sustains.

Comment: There seems to be an issue in linking a direct file on Github. I've linked to the Gem. The file of interest would be the one located at /lib/annotate/annotate_models.rb

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an automated way to do this, other than editing the generator code.

You could consider using a snippet for your editor of choice.